# CSS issues with magicsuggest

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, magicsuggest

I am using [magicsuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/index.html) for tagging. I have added all required dependencies (i.e. jquery and bootstrap) and have a very simple HTML page as below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tags" class="control-label">Tags</label>
                <img src="~/images/help-small.png" alt="Help" class="help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Press ENTER or TAB for a new tag." />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS is below:

```
 $('#tags').magicSuggest({
        useTabKey: true,
        minChars: 3,
        typeDelay: 300,
        placeholder: "e.g. rock or pop",
        valueField: 'Id',
        displayField: 'Name',
        data: window.apiUrl + 'tags',
        method: 'GET',
        hideTrigger: true
    });
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't get it to display the suggestions box at all! After a bit of debugging with firebug, I found out that it creates a DIV element with "ms-res-ctn dropdown-menu" classes. "dropdown-menu" is a default bootstrap class:

```
<div class="ms-res-ctn dropdown-menu" style="height: 41px;"><div class="ms-res-item ms-res-item-active" data-json="{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Blues&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;:&quot;quoque non esset et quantare nomen non plurissimum estis Pro gravis quad et pars homo, vobis Quad pars apparens quartu et&quot;,&quot;Id&quot;:&quot;be8c735b-7c3e-9154-d1ec-dd2d67c161eb&quot;}"><em>Blue</em>s</div></div>

.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I had to hack the "dropdown-menu" CSS class and overwrite with the below attributes:

```
margin: 6px -13px 0;
position: relative;
```

This seems really dodgy to me given that all live examples work perfectly. Apologies for my basic CSS skills but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks for your comment, didn't think about trying with jsfiddle. It turns out I can't reproduce it and will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I did say my CSS skills were pretty bad and that's sad!

I found out I had a rule in my base.css that was screwing up with the magicsuggest's results:

```
.form-group {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Why? I have no idea!